# changing specific area from character to numeric in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I use Rstudio and imported a csv file from online.

```
data <- read.csv("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In the file, column X.3 is of type character.

I want to convert row (5 to 202) from character to numeric so that I can calculate mean of it.

So, when I use this line below. It still remains as character

```
data[c(5:202),"X.3"] <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data[c(5:202),"X.3"]))
```

when i type `class(data[10,"X.3"])` it shows the output as `character`

I am able to convert the whole column to numeric using

```
data[,"X.3"] <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data[,"X.3"]))
```

but i want to convert only specific row's ie from 5 to 202 beacause the other rows of the column becomes `N/A`. i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: It's because if a column has characters already and you're trying to append it with numeric, R implictly coerces it to the character and this is called implicit coercsion

Comment: you will use `data[,"X.3"]=as.numeric(gsub("\\D+","",data[,"X.3"]))`

Comment: I want to retain other rows in the column as characters ie apart from row 5 to row 202. This code changes the whole column to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes to your code can help you make it numeric:

```
data <- read.csv("http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/GDP.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, skip = 3)
# skipping first 3 rows which is just empty space/junk and defining the one as header

data <- data[-1,]
#removing the first line after the header 

data$US.dollars. <- as.numeric(gsub(',','',data$US.dollars.))
#replacing scientific comma with blank to convert the character to numeric

hist(data$US.dollars.) #sample plot
```

As mentioned in the comment, you cannot keep part of your column as character and part numeric because R doesn't allow that and it forces type conversion to a higher order in this case numeric to character. You can read here more about [Implicit Coercion of R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/)

Comment: You see with the data given, almost the first 5 rows are all characters. So by just removing the first row, the problem. Rows 204:222 has periods while other rows are whitespaces, thus your code has not taken this into consideration. Therefore will fail